# Perturbation of a linear homogeneous equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Let $A$ be a $n\times(n+1)$ matrix, full row rank. Let $\tilde A=A+\Delta A$ be a perturbation of $A$, again with full row rank.

I am interested what is known about bounds on the angle between the kernel $x$ of $A$ ($Ax=0$) and the kernel $\tilde x$ of $\tilde A$ ($\tilde A \tilde x=0$).  Namely, a bound on 
$\frac{x^T\tilde x}{|x||\tilde x|}$.

Could somebody hint me some good literature?

Comment: What do you mean bounds on the angle between the kernels? The kernels are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, what is the angle between two subspaces? Perhaps it makes sense when the two are one dimensional, but otherwise it seems to make no sense.

Comment: it's quite common to define angles between subspaces. These are called principal angles [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats). But I am also fine with the simple result when the kernel is one dimensional, thus I change the question.